# Is it possible to post a helpful tutorial onto ROS website

Tags: ros, matlab, ros-melodic, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have accomplished a few important things in my project that I would like to contribute to the ROS community in the form of a tutorial.
The project is regarding MATLAB visual studio on windows communication with ros on ubuntu over the network.

Is it possible? and if so how do i go about doing so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339373/is-it-possible-to-post-a-helpful-tutorial-onto-ros-website/) by [humzaChoudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/44167/humzachoudry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-12-06**:
+1 thanks for your interest! The ROS Wiki is a good place to start!

**Comment by [humzaChoudry](https://answers.ros.org/users/44167/humzachoudry/) on 2019-12-06**:
But how do i publish a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up an account on the ROS wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/action/newaccount/Documentation?action=newaccount

Once you have an account, you can post on this issue to request edit access to the wiki: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/258 (we've had a lot of spam, and this helps prevent bots from taking over the wiki)

Then you can create new wiki pages or update an existing tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1